# How to get all class on android app running

Tags: java

I just wanna get all class from my android project,someone suggest me to use dexfile,so,I try it.but it can not get all class ,for example,my packagename is "org.zj",I just wanna get some class which name start with "org.zj" but it response me "android.support.xxx" or "android.arch.xxx" .this is my code

```
 public static List<Class> getClasses(Activity activity) {
    List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String packageName = activity.getPackageName();
        System.out.println(packageName + " 包名");
        //String packageCodePath = activity.getPackageCodePath();
        classes.addAll(getClasses(packageName));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return classes;
}

public static List<Class> getClasses(String packageName) {
    List<Class> classes=new ArrayList<>();
    List<DexFile> multiDex = getMultiDex();
    for (DexFile df : multiDex) {
        classes.addAll(getClassByDexFile(df,packageName));
    }
    return classes;
}

public static ArrayList<DexFile> getMultiDex() {
    BaseDexClassLoader dexLoader = (BaseDexClassLoader) ClassUtil.class.getClassLoader();
    Field f = ClassUtil.getField("pathList", "dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader");
    Object pathList = getObjectFromField(f, dexLoader);
    Field f2 = ClassUtil.getField("dexElements", "dalvik.system.DexPathList");
    Object[] list = (Object[]) getObjectFromField(f2, pathList);
    Field f3 = ClassUtil.getField("dexFile", "dalvik.system.DexPathList$Element");

    ArrayList<DexFile> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        DexFile d = (DexFile) getObjectFromField(f3, list[i]);
        res.add(d);
    }

    return res;
}

public static List<Class> getClassByDexFile(DexFile dexFile, String packageName) {
    List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    DexFile df = dexFile;
    //String regExp = "^" + packageName + ".\\w+$";
    for (Enumeration iter = df.entries(); iter.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        String className = (String) iter.nextElement();
        System.out.println(className + "");
        if (className.contains(packageName)) {
            try {
                classes.add(Class.forName(className));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return classes;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal? (So why do you want to have all your class names?)

Comment: generate proxy class and DI,get annotation and handle,I just wanna write a framework for android ,easy to development

Comment: I see, do you require the modifications in the running APP or would generated code for the sourcecode be sufficient? If the latter, have a look at the Annotation Processing Tool.